# What do the clock badges on scratch file icons mean in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, sometimes a scratch file will have a small clock symbol in the bottom right of its icon, like `scratch.html` below.

[image]

What do these clock badges mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This icon](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/0b6b58d908931df442e55bd01c1277a81c3dff5f/platform/icons/src/actions/scratch.png) indicates that the file is a [scratch file](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/6c92c6ab6d18e2bf9e67d207a7d96d469caf9cae/platform/util/src/com/intellij/icons/AllIcons.java#L153), it's an [overlay added](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/edd577d5c3c0cc07065df913e944b8e64609773d/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/scratch/ScratchRootType.java#L58) to the file type icon.

I think the meaning of the icon is that the file is a **temporary** one and doesn't belong to the project.